# Appending JSON object inside state of component and displaying it

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I have a function to which I am passing the state of an object. Inside the function I am performing some operations on the state. Now I want to update the state with the operations I have performed and display it as an JSON object.

I have my state as :

```
state= {
    company: "xyz",
    employee: {
        name:["a","b"],
        age: [13,14]
      },
      details: {
        salary:[],
        dept:[]
      }
   }
}
```

I have a function in which I have populated the values of salary and dept

```
function updatestate(state){
//some operations..
//const output has values 
//output variable has something like this stored in it=> 
// salary:[["2500"],["4000"]] , dept:[["fin"],["mkt"]] 
}
```

the state object passed has all the values; now I want to append the values of salary and dept inside filters.

Expected output is :

```
state= {
    company: "xyz",
    employee: {
        name:["a","b"],
        age: [13,14]
      },
      details: {
        salary:[["2500"],["4000"]] , 
        dept:[["fin"],["mkt"]]
      }
   }
}
```

I tried manual coding:

```
//inside the function updatestate(state)

 const state_json = {details : output} 
 return JSON.stringify(state_json);
```

But I want to show the entire state and find a way to automatically append the values into the state and display as JSON

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with your issue, but I think you can use **JSON.stringify()** Fn for the same.

```js
let state= {
    company: "xyz",
    employee: {
        name:["a","b"],
        age: [13,14]
      },
    details: {
      salary:[],
      dept:[]
    }
   };

function updatestate(state) {
  const baseData = {
   salary:[["2500"],["4000"]] , 
   dept:[["fin"],["mkt"]] 
  };
  state.details.salary = baseData.salary;
  state.details.dept = baseData.dept;
  return state;
}

state = updatestate(state);
console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
```

Comment: this wont work for me as the values for salary and dept are not fixed. It is with the user. So, I just gave the values as an example.